# Decode NSDictionary with functions inside as values to swift object

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nsdictionary, decode

any advices or suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks!

I have an issue to solve and it seems I can't find the answer anywhere. Some context: we are updating our ios app and the production version is written in obj-c, but new UI features we develop in Swift. Therefore we have a dictionary with some values for our Swift side of development which contains a lot of important data for the UI. As for now we are just looping the dict to fetch the values. I want to convert it to a swift object, so it would be easier to access the needed values. The problem is that the dictionary contains values that are function calls and UIImage type. What would be the smartest way to parse this dictionary to a swift object? The dictionary:

```
let dict : [String: Any] = [
    "keySelectedMenuButton" : 0,
    "keySettButtCallback"  : settTapCallback,
    "keyInfoButtCallback"  : logoTapCallback,
    "keyObjectMenuCallback": menuButtonTapCallback,
    "buttonListChanged"    : doneEditTapCallback,
    "keyObjectArray"      : [
        ["keyObjectTitle"    : "Home",
         //  "keyObjectLineImage": UIImage(named: "objektu atskyrimas_4x")!,
            "keyObjCtrlButtCollectionArray" : [
                
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Smart Menu",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //"keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_rocket")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap1Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Lock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "doors",
                 //"keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_1@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Unlock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "Gates",
                 // "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_0@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Ignore",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //  "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_shield@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap1Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Stop",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //  "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_stop")!
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap2Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "State",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //   "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_query@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap3Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Controller",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //   "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_settings_lines")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap1Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Logs",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //  "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_log@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap2Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Notifications",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //   "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_notifications")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap3Callback
                ]]
        ],
        ["keyObjectTitle":"Auto",
         //"keyObjectLineImage": UIImage(named: "objektu atskyrimas_4x")!,
            "keyObjCtrlButtCollectionArray" : [
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Smart Menu",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //  "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_rocket")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap2Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Lock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "Backdoor",
                 //   "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_1@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Unlock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "Fence",
                 //    "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_0@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Ignore",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //    "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_shield@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap1Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Stop",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //   "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_stop")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap3Callback
                ]]
        ],
        ["keyObjectTitle":"Basement",
         //   "keyObjectLineImage": UIImage(),
            "keyObjCtrlButtCollectionArray" : [
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Smart Menu",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //    "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_rocket")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTap1Callback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Lock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //      "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_1@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ],
                ["keyCtrlItemTitle"      : "Unlock",
                 "keyCtrlItemSubtitle"   : "",
                 //         "keyCtrlItemImage"      : UIImage(named: "ico_lock_0@x3")!,
                    "keyCtrlObjectAfterTap" : buttonTapCallback
                ]]
        ]
    ]
]


func logoTapCallback(){
    print("logo tapped")

}

func menuButtonTapCallback() {
    print("menu button tapped ")
    
}

func buttonTapCallback(){
    print("button tapped")
    
}

func buttonTap1Callback(){
    print("button tapped 1")
}

func buttonTap2Callback(){
    print("button tapped 2")
}

func buttonTap3Callback(){
    print("button tapped 3")
}

func settTapCallback(){
    print("settTap")
}

func doneEditTapCallback(){
    print("doneEditTap")
}


// Dictionary structure I would like to use:

struct InitialDictionaryStructure {
    var keySelectedMenuButton            : Int
    var keySettButtCallback              : ()->Void
    var keyInfoButtCallback              : ()->Void
    var keyObjectMenuCallback            : ()->Void
    var buttonListChanged                : ()->Void
    var keyObjectArray                   : [[Object]]
    
}

struct Object {
    var keyObjectTitle                   : String
    //var keyObjectLineImage               : UIImage
    var keyObjCtrlButtCollectionArray    : [Button]
    
    
}

struct Button {
    var keyCtrlItemTitle                 : String
    var keyCtrlItemSubtitle              : String
    //var keyCtrlItemImage                 : UIImage
    var keyCtrlObjectAfterTap            : ()-> Void
}
```

Comment: Since functions are not JSON or PropertyList compliant you have to write a custom `init(dictionary : [String:Any])` method in each struct and assign the values *manually*.

Comment: @vadian thanks for your answer. Maybe by any chance you might provide an example how the implementation would look like? Would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *smart* way, you have to add initializers.

If the values are not going to be modified declare the struct members as constant and I shortened the member names slightly omitting redundant information.

```
struct InitialDictionaryStructure {
    let menuButton            : Int
    let settButtCallback      : ()->Void
    let infoButtCallback      : ()->Void
    let objectMenuCallback    : ()->Void
    let buttonListChanged     : ()->Void
    let objects               : [Object]
    
    init(dictionary : [String:Any]) {
        menuButton = dictionary["keySelectedMenuButton"] as! Int
        settButtCallback = dictionary["keySettButtCallback"] as! ()-> Void
        infoButtCallback = dictionary["keyInfoButtCallback"] as! ()-> Void
        objectMenuCallback = dictionary["keyObjectMenuCallback"] as! ()-> Void
        buttonListChanged = dictionary["buttonListChanged"] as! ()-> Void
        let objectData = dictionary["keyObjectArray"] as! [[String:Any]]
        objects = objectData.map(Object.init)
    }
}

struct Object {
    let title                  : String
    // let lineImage           : UIImage
    let buttons                : [Button]
    
    init(dictionary : [String:Any]) {
        title = dictionary["keyObjectTitle"] as! String
        // lineImage = dictionary["keyObjectLineImage"] as! UIImage
        let buttonData = dictionary["keyObjCtrlButtCollectionArray"] as! [[String:Any]]
        buttons = buttonData.map(Button.init)
    }
}

struct Button {
    let title                 : String
    let subtitle              : String
    // let image                 : UIImage
    let objectAfterTap        : ()-> Void
    
    init(dictionary : [String:Any]) {
        title = dictionary["keyCtrlItemTitle"] as! String
        subtitle = dictionary["keyCtrlItemSubtitle"] as! String
        // image = dictionary["keyCtrlItemImage"] as! UIImage
        objectAfterTap = dictionary["keyCtrlObjectAfterTap"] as! ()-> Void
    }
}
```

Please consider that this is a simple example without any type and `nil` checks. If the dictionaries don't contain all keys with the proper types the code will crash.

To create an item write

```
let initialDictionaryStructure = InitialDictionaryStructure(dictionary: dict)
print(initialDictionaryStructure)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the explanations! I appreciate it! I think I will manage everything from now on myself, thanks once again.